# How to connect to hive using python pyhs2?

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, thrift

I am trying to access hive using `pyhs2`. I tried the following code:

example.py

```
import pyhs2
conn = pyhs2.connect(host='localhost', port=10000,authMechanism=None, user=None, password=None,database='default')
with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute("select * from table")
        for i in cur.fetch():
            print i
```

I am getting the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "example.py", line 2, in <module> conn = pyhs2.connect(host='localhost', port=10000,authMechanism=None, user=None, password=None,database='default')
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyhs2/__init__.py", line 7, in connect
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyhs2/connections.py", line 46, in __init__
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyhs2/cloudera/thrift_sasl.py", line 55, in open
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/thrift/transport/TSocket.py", line 101, in open
    thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: Could not connect to localhost:10000
```

I am getting the exact error when I try with hive utils. I have checked sasl installation. Do I need to make any changes to the hive-site.xml in hive? If yes where do I need to create it? Am I missing out something?

Comment: Are you using hortonworks? Do you have access to Ambari?

Comment: No I am not using hortonworks

Answer (score 1):

1- Figure out the IP address of the localhost using (on Linux):

```
hostname -I
```

2- Change localhost to the actual ip

I would also suggest that you double check which host Hive is on. If you are using hortonworks, on Ambari, go to `Hive`, then `Configs` and check the host there.

**Edit** (adding another suggestion):

Your username and password most likely aren't `None`. To get your username and password, check `hive-site.xml` and look at the values in `javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName` and `javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword`. If you can't find anything, try an empty string as the password (as opposed to None), and `hive` or empty string as the username i.e. try these one by one:

`conn = pyhs2.connect(host='localhost', port=10000,authMechanism='PLAIN', user='hive', password='',database='default')`

`conn = pyhs2.connect(host='localhost', port=10000,authMechanism='PLAIN', user='', password='',database='default')`

Note that I also changed `authMechanism` to `"PLAIN"`

Comment: Ok I edited my answer to suggest different username and password combinations that might work. It's most likely not None

Comment: @highonprogramming How can I connect to remote server? Do i need to run any commands on CLI (like starting the server)?

Comment: @Mrunmayee you need to start your hive server from commandline "hive —service hiveserver2"

Comment: @highonprogramming Remote server - No. am just able to connect to hive on localhost.

Comment: I just put the ip of the remote server. Try to ping the ip you used and make sure it's right. Maybe you are using a private ip instead of a public ip or something like that.