# How to connect to Hadoop Hive through python via pyhs2?

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, connection-string

I've installed `Hadoop` eco system on `OS X`. And I have installed `pyhs2` python package in order to connect to hive and query the database. The code I use is as below:

```
import pyhs2


with pyhs2.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                   port=10000,
                   authMechanism="PLAIN",
                   user='admin',
                   password='1234qwer',
                   database='cards') as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        #Show databases
        print cur.getDatabases()

        #Execute query
        cur.execute("select * from users")

        #Return column info from query
        print cur.getSchema()

        #Fetch table results
        for i in cur.fetch():
            print i
```

In `hive` config file `/usr/local/opt/hive/libexec/conf/hive-default.xml` I have set `username` and `password` to `admin` and `1234qwer`.

Now when I run the python script it gives the below error:

```
thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:10000
```

Similar question in stack overflow:

[How to connect to hive using python pyhs2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140953/how-to-connect-to-hive-using-python-pyhs2)

I can go to `hive` through terminal and all things work as expected.

The weird thing is that I checked whether port 10000 is open or not by using `lsof -i -P | grep -i 'listen'"` but the port is not listed there!

Any help?

Comment: How do you know that's the correct port of Hive server?

Comment: And you installed a single node cluster on a Mac, so I don't understand why not just use MySQL?

Comment: @cricket_007 https://ambari.apache.org/1.2.3/installing-hadoop-using-ambari/content/reference_chap2_3.html

Comment: @cricket_007 I am testing the ecosystem in local.

Comment: And you have installed Hive Server 2 through Ambari?

Comment: @cricket_007, I've said on `MAC OS X`! `Ambari` is used on linux ditros.

Comment: I just wanted to show you the port which hive uses, that's why I used ambari link

Comment: I see, but you probably should have linked here instead.  Anyways, so the server isn't running - is that the problem? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Setting+Up+HiveServer2

Comment: @cricket_007 it is actually running, as I have said in the question I can work with hive through terminal.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you, then. And that library is no longer maintained either.  https://github.com/BradRuderman/pyhs2/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120958/discussion-between-alireza-hos-and-cricket-007).